# How to disable the search text popup when filtering a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

When using a filtered ListView, how do I disable the popup that shows the filter text above the ListView? It's obscuring the ListView and I'd like to prevent it from showing, but so far I haven't been able to find a suitable workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove popup text from listview filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999083/how-do-i-remove-popup-text-from-listview-filter)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this on the standard `ListView`, you may have to extend it. Alternatively, if you have your own `EditText` on screen (I can't tell for sure, but the picture you posted looks like there is one), you can do something like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id_goes_here);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
popupwindow pw = .....
```

to get rid of it then put

```
pw.dismiss();
```

in an ok button on the popup layout

Comment: I'm not asking how to create a new popup window. I'm asking how to get rid of the one that's automatically created in the ListView that I don't want to show.

Comment: don't create it then in the first place

Comment: It's automatically created for you. Did you even read my question?

Answer (score -2):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
```