# How do I remove popup text from listview filter?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a text filter on a ListView and I'd like to get rid of the popup view that shows what the filter text is. Is there any way to remove this view?

Some example code:

```
    ArrayList<String> buildingNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, buildingNames));
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    list.setFilterText("test_filter");
```

When I set the filter text, a really ugly view pops up at the bottom of the ListView that shows what the current filter text is:

[image: ListView filter text popup]

Comment: Please provide some example source code that you're using isolated to show the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer here:
http://markmail.org/message/7uju6bmmaswag2lu:

> By calling setTextFilterEnabled() you do request this popup. If you
>   don't want it, disable text filtering. This is an interactive feature
>   for the user. It is not meant to be used programatically. If you want
>   to programatically filter your adapter, call getFilter() on your
>   adapter directly (if your adapter supports filtering.)
>
> Romain Guy

So rather than using setTextFilterEnabled you need to work with the filter directly like so:

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = (customAdapter)myListView.getAdapter();
Filter filter = customAdapter .getFilter();
filter.filter("search string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this change

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            System.out.println("tap");
            yourAdapter ca = (yourAdapter)listview.getAdapter();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                System.out.println("isEmpty");
                //listview.clearTextFilter();  
                ca.getFilter().filter(null);
            } else {

                ca.getFilter().filter(newText);
                //listview.setFilterText(newText);

            }
            return true;
        }
```