# How to hide the filter popup on ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, popup

I `setTextFilterEnabled` for text filtering a `ListView`. Filtering is working fine, but a popup window showing the filter text appears when I type. See image:

[image: ListView filter text popup]

How can I hide this popup or change its position on the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove popup text from listview filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999083/how-do-i-remove-popup-text-from-listview-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter.publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) is probably what pops up. And therefore you probably need to subclass Filter and override it.

Best regards.

Comment: Filter.FilterResults is not visible. I think it's not possible to override this method

Comment: `Filter.publishResults(...)` **has** to be overridden to create a filter, this is not where that popup is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

I have found easier solution that works for me on this blog:

http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=128

When you create `ArrayAdapter` to populate `ListView`, just store reference to its Filter and then you can simply modify Filter on `ArrayAdapter` instead of `ListView`.

*In Xamarin you can just use `arrayAdapter.InvokeFilter("my text");`

Answer (score 3):

Create a filter , ( you may be using a different adapter )

```
ContentAdapter  adapter = new ContentAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            s);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    Filter f = adapter.getFilter();
```

Then use filter inside 'onQueryTextChange', instead of the commented code

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {

            //list1.clearTextFilter();
            f.filter(null);
        } else {
            //list1.setFilterText(newText.toString());
            f.filter(newText);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  as Vatsal mentioned you can create a filter from the adapter. So the way in which I solved this was that I created an ArrayAdapter as a class variable.

```
// ...
private void setListAdapter() {
    List<Word> words = Dictionary.getInstance(this).getWords();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            words);
    // Sets the List Adapter that we are using
    this.setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
// ...
```

then from this class variable in the onQueryTextChange or onQueryTextSubmit you can get the filter like so

```
//...
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    // By doing this it removes the popup completely which was arising from using the this.getListView().setFilterText(query) method
    arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

    return true;
}
//...
```