# Android SearchView filtered listview - how to remove query box?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-search

I have added a SearchView to an ActionBar which filters a ListView.

Everything works fine, the only problem is when I write a query in the SearchView, the query text also appears in a box in the middle of the screen in big fonts.

I guess it is some kind of query preview.. How do I cancel this?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that before. What phone are you running this on?

Comment: Nexus 4. This is the search filter demo from the APIDemos sample. (so not my code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the way you implement onQueryTextChange. I comment listview.clearTextFilter(); and change that for ca.getFilter().filter(null);

Here is the code I used

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            System.out.println("tap");
            yourAdapter ca = (yourAdapter)listview.getAdapter();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                System.out.println("isEmpty");
                //listview.clearTextFilter();
                ca.getFilter().filter(null);
            } else {

                ca.getFilter().filter(newText);
                //listview.setFilterText(newText);

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the text filter on the `ListView` (actually of its super class `AbsListview`]. Get a handle of the `ListView` and call

```
    yourListview.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
```

See the API documentation of [AbsListView.setTextFilterEnabled(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29).

If you're curious: They use a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to display the currently entered query text.

Comment: This works but if I use it then I can't filer the listview by text. I do want to filter just without the popup window.

Comment: @Ran, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999083/how-do-i-remove-popup-text-from-listview-filter) you've got the solution. It involves managing the adapter's filter yourself.