# Weird textbox appeared on search

Tags: android

As on the picture linked below, there is a dark textbox on the center of the screen as user enter the text on searchView. How to get rid of that?

[image]

Search related code in my MainActivity.java

```
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    searchview = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                listView.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                listView.setFilterText(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Search related code on my MyAdapter.java

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<DrugItem> results = new ArrayList<DrugItem>();
            if (filteredItemsArrayList == null)
                filteredItemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (itemsArrayList != null && filteredItemsArrayList.size() > 0) {
                    for (final DrugItem g : filteredItemsArrayList) {
                        if (g.getDrugGenericName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()) || g.getDrugBrandName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            itemsArrayList = (ArrayList<DrugItem>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Search related code in my activity_main.xml

```
    <SearchView
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toprow"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Enter Drug Name To Filter......." />
```

Comment: This seems like a centered view, are you sure you don't have this declared in your xml somewhere accidently?

Comment: I have added Search related code in my activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I remove popup text from listview filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999083/how-do-i-remove-popup-text-from-listview-filter)

i Searched this was answered before as the link above. There is no solution. Use other way to do filtering instead of setTextFilterEnabled(true)